# Saving Keyring Password

Tags: firefox, login, password, keyrings, seahorse

I have found the answer to this but I'm posting it here in case others have the same issue and also asking if anyone has any more details ;-)

I use Firefox and Thundirbird's "Gnome Keyring Password Integration" Plugin by Guillermo Molina available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-keyring-integration/

Everything has been working perfectly except that every time I start Firefox or Thunderbird I have to enter my keyring password, even if it's the same as my login password.

I could find nothing online about automatically loging in to keyrings **other than the Default 'login' keyring**

I was about to post a question here when I noticed the little *Details* drop down in the bottom of the password prompt. Looking here I found four options, the first of which was "Automatically unlock keychain at login" or something to this effect.

Setting this solved the problem, even if the keyring's password is **not my login password.**

Now if anyone can tell me how to change this back again now that it's set and the password prompt doesn't popup any more I'd be very grateful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you're asked to provide a keyring password and you unlock it with the mentioned checkbox checked, passwords manager adds the new record to your default keyring - you can open "Passwords and Keys" application (seahorse), select your default keyring and remove unwanted records.